# Can't write PHP cookies or sessions on RackSpace server

Tags: php, session, cookies

I'm working on a RackSpace server, and I am unable to successfully write cookies or persistent sessions through PHP (I can write javascript cookies just fine).

The cookies are never written at all, and the sessions are never accessible on any page but the one they're written on. I've tried the exact same code on a different server, and it worked just fine -- so I'm assuming it's some kind of configuration issue.

Here's an example:

**Sessions**

Page 1:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['mysession'] = 'hello';
//writes correct value
echo $_SESSION['mysession'];
```

Page 2:

```
session_start();
//this dumps 'NULL'
var_dump($_SESSION['mysession']);
```

**Cookies:**

```
//this never gets written.
setcookie($mycookie, $myvalue, time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
```

Are there any particular server settings I should be looking at?

I ran phpinfo, and see my session.save_path. I tried setting that to 777 just to see if it would help, but it did not.

I'm stumped, and their support couldn't help me. Anyone have any ideas?

**Edit:**

Upon closer inspection, I can see that the sessions are being written -- I just can't read them.

Answer (score 0):

You can gather more information by creating a php file with content:

```
<?php phpinfo();
```

Request this site and search for the session settings.
- Are sessions really enabled?
- Which session save handler is used?

Maybe the session data is not even saved in a file and the error is anywhere else.

Comment: Session support is enabled.

the save handlers are 'files user'

Comment: Upon closer inspection, I see that the sessions are being written to the session.save_path directory, I just don't seem to be able to read them.

Comment: Which webserver software are you using? Including the version.

Comment: This is your operating system. Are you using apache, nginx or something else as webserver? Did you had already a look at your logfiles? Maybe not only the webserver has good information for this problem. And last but not least: have you tried to turn it off and on again? Sometimes a reboot even works on linux. :)

Comment: Looking at an error log, I see 'Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name' -- trying to troubleshoot that now and see if it helps

Comment: It will not help. Simply set ServerName to a fqdn, this will fix this problem. But it will not fix your session issue.

Comment: Damn. That's the only thing I see in my error logs.

Comment: recheck if your two files really contain the above lines and double check the behaviour again. Is it still like at the beginning?

Comment: I did. I can verify that the sesssions are being written to the correct folder. The problem seems to be reading them -- even when I set the folder and session files to 777 (not a good idea I know, but I'm troubleshooting here)

Comment: Check the accessibility of the files by hand by trying to do a "sudo -u apache cat /path/to/session/sess_file". If there's a problem in accessing the session file with the user your webserver runs with this should fail.

Comment: You're right! Here's the response:

sudo: unknown user: apache
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: Maybe your webserver is running on a different user. Check it with "ps aux | grep apache". Then do the sudo command from before with the user you've found.

Comment: Yes, it is running on www-data. When I ran sudo -u cat www-data /path I was able to read the session fine.